# Looking for downloadable demo of a .Net service accessed through a pure JavaScript client, without relying on IIS to serve the service

Tags: .net, javascript

I am told that the configuration below is possible, but have had significant difficulty in finding instructions on how to set it up. While I'm trying to muddle my way through this on my own, maybe stack-overflow knows of better sources for documentation:

I am looking for a walkthrough, including a downloadable, working example, for setting up the following configuration:

Server-side .net application (For .net 2.0 or higher), installed/deployed as a windows' service (that is, not served through IIS), and accessed by a client tool that is completely implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can host a ASMX webservice now without IIS, you can use the new HTTP protocol stack available called http.sys.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, but seems to be the closest available online at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can host an ASMX web service without using IIS by using the Neokernel Web Server (www.neokernel.com), there is an example of this in the Demos provided with the installation. You can distribute the neokernel assembly with your assembly, bootstrap the Neokernel server in your application code so it listens on the port you specify, and shut the server down in your application code when you don't need the ASMX service to be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .NET 3.5, then you can host a WCF service within a windows service. The WCF service can be either SOAP or REST-based.

You cannot host an ASMX web service outside of IIS.